# Having shape issues when doing prediction with Keras2 of test and train data with an LSTM model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm, reshape

**Problem:**
When I run the `model.predict()` on `test_X` and `train_X` I get a shape mismatch when I try to learn how to predict 1 step into the future using n amount TimeSteps for lookback.

**What I am using:**
Windows10, 
Python3.8,
Keras 2.3.1,
inside conda venv

**I have tried:**
Created Supervised training set from Train and Test data using the examples from https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/.
I have tried many examples from here and MachineLearningMastery and ended with this last one. https://www.pytorials.com/predict-cryptocurrency-price-using-lstm/. I think I might have read the correct answer somewhere in the last 2 days but are now so info swamped, not entirely sure what is next anymore.

```
# define model 
model = Sequential() 
model.add(LSTM(50, activation= 'relu' , input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]))) 
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
callback = [EarlyStopping(monitor="loss", min_delta = 0.00001, patience = 20, mode = 'auto', restore_best_weights=True)]

# fit model
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=100, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=1, 
                    batch_size=16, shuffle=False, callbacks=callback)
```

The plots show that the loss and the val_loss converge good and nothing out of the ordinary.

Here are the shapes of my data just before prediction.

```
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
(25607, 60, 3) (25607,) (6360, 60, 3) (6360,)
```

```
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(train_X)
testPredict = model.predict(test_X)
# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform(train_y)
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform(test_y)
# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(train_y[:,0], trainPredict[:,0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_y[:,0], testPredict[:,0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-11d08dc2a08f> in <module>
      3 testPredict = model.predict(test_X)
      4 # invert predictions
----> 5 trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
      6 trainY = scaler.inverse_transform(train_y)
      7 testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)

c:\users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in inverse_transform(self, X)
    434                         force_all_finite="allow-nan")
    435 
--> 436         X -= self.min_
    437         X /= self.scale_
    438         return X

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (25607,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (25607,4)
```

PS: Where does the 4 come from as not one of my other shapes have it.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

**EDIT**
Also tried reshaping the predictors as follows but with the same error:

```
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict.reshape(-1,1))
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform(train_y)
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict.reshape(-1,1))
testY = scaler.inverse_transform(test_y)
```

Comment: Hello,  
I don't understand why you are doing `trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)`.
Moreover, your error comes from `trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)` not from `model.predict()`

Comment: Just saw a post here where they reshaped the inverse from eg. (400, ) to (400,1) and it helped his cause, but not here. And in the original error it had this arrow. ```----> 5 trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)``` So I thought the issue might be there